# How Can I write a Fibonacci sequence, which uses an array?

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
class Fibonacci {
    static final int MIN_INDEX = 1;
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int high = 1;
        int low = 1;
        String jel;
        System.out.println("9: " + high);

      for (int i = 8; i >= MIN_INDEX; i--){
        if (high % 2 == 0)
          jel = " *";
        else 
          jel = " ";
        System.out.println(i + ": " + high + jel);
        high = low + high;
        low = high - low;
      }
   }
}
```

I want to write this program, to store the Fibonacci sequence in an array, and then write out them. But I can't write it. What can I do? I don't need to "mark them" with an *.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, add the homework tag, please.

Comment: It almost has to be homework, doesn't it?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question, linked under RELATED ?

Comment: I ran it and got this output:
`9: 1  
8: 1   
7: 2 *  
6: 3   
5: 5   
4: 8 *  
3: 13   
2: 21   
1: 34 *`    
Is this what you want?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Are you having problems declaring an array? Writing out data contained in an array? Understanding what an array has to do with the Fibonacci sequence? It sounds like you genuinely want assistance, but the way your question is written now, it looks like a "write some code for me" post, which isn't really what we do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will answer your question (I also added handling for some pessimistic scenarios):

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] fibMembers = buildFibArray(9);
        printFibArray(fibMembers);
    }

    private static void printFibArray(int[] fibMembers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fibMembers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(fibMembers.length-i);
            System.out.print(": ");
            System.out.print(fibMembers[i]);
            if (fibMembers[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private static int[] buildFibArray(int maxIndex)
    {
        int[] fibMembers = new int[maxIndex];

        if (maxIndex > 0)
        {
            fibMembers[0] = 1;
            if (maxIndex > 1)
            {
                fibMembers[1] = 1;

                for (int i = 2; i < fibMembers.length; i++)
                {
                    fibMembers[i] = fibMembers[i-2] + fibMembers[i-1];
                }
            }
        }
        return fibMembers;
    }
}
```

The `buildFibArray` method builds the array.
The `printFibArray` method prints the array - should be according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here are the steps

1. Calculate the Fibonacci Sequence numbers that you need; store each value.
2. Print the values that you calculated.

#### Calculate and store the Fibonacci Numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is a recursive function, but it would be ridiculous to implement it in any probramming language using recursion.  Instead use a loop.  For example:

```
int[] fibonacciNumbers = new int[20];
fibonacciNumbers[0] = 0;
fibonacciNumbers[1] = 1;

for (int index = 2; index < fibonacciNumbers.length; ++index)
{
    fibonacciNumbers[index] = fibonacciNumbers[index - 1] + fibonacciNumbers[index - 2];
}
```

#### Print the array

Loop through each element in the array and print it however you want; for example, you could `System.out.println(fibonacciNumbers[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only pair Fibonacci numbers :

```
public class Fibonacci {       

    private int count = 0;

    public Integer next() {
        return fib(count++);
    }

    private int fib(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> pairFib = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Fibonacci gen = new Fibonacci();
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        int current = gen.next();
        if (current % 2 == 0) {
            pairFib.add(current);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pairFib);
}
```

}

Comment: if you replace your recursive function call by an array reference, this will give the OP what he/she wants